# How to download and connect MySql for my Traccar opensource project for GPS Tracking

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gps, h2, liquibase

I have downloaded and install traccar project from Github to use in GPS tracking features. The current project uses H2 Database for the store the device location. the library is used to connect this is liquibase. So how can I connect My sql to it.

Code Downloaded from here
https://www.traccar.org

Comment: Try changing the setting in this file to point to your mysql installation and then deploy the project https://github.com/traccar/traccar/blob/master/setup/traccar.xml

Comment: You want to connect from your code or from IDE interface (to run the queries in IDE)? If from IDE interface, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/connecting-to-a-database.html#mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One day of struggle finally I completed.
1). First, install SQL in my pc and create a database.
2). Add below line in a  traccar.xml

```
<entry key='database.driver'>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</entry>
<entry key='database.url'>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/traccar?serverTimezone=UTC&amp;useSSL=false&amp;allowMultiQueries=true&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;sessionVariables=sql_mode=''</entry>
<entry key='database.user'>root</entry>
<entry key='database.password'></entry>
```

3). same code add in your debug.xml file

```
<entry key='database.driver'>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</entry>
<entry key='database.url'>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/traccar?serverTimezone=UTC&amp;useSSL=false&amp;allowMultiQueries=true&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;sessionVariables=sql_mode=''</entry>
<entry key='database.user'>root</entry>
<entry key='database.password'></entry>
```

4). Now rebuild the project and run 
In the console, you can see the tables are created by the project itself.